# BluetoothGattCallback onCharacteristicRead never called back

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm still trying hard to read from a BLE device (laser meter) from an android (using java)
Basically I'm trying to get which fields are those I'm interested into (aka the measures)

So far i discovered 5 services (i found the usage [here](https://btprodspecificationrefs.blob.core.windows.net/assigned-values/16-bit%20UUID%20Numbers%20Document.pdf)):

- 3ab10100-f831-4395-b29d-570977d5bf94 (I can't figure out what is this bad boy usage)
- 0x1800 -> probably the ones I'm looking for
- 0x1801 -> idk (only writable characteristics so idc)
- 0x180a -> device name (I am able to read the name from this one)
- 0x180f -> battery

the first problem i met is that, according to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback#onCharacteristicRead(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt,%20android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic,%20int)), onCharacteristicRead(3) is deprecated since API 13 as it adds now an array of byte as parameter. But according to Android studio, this overload does not exist.

The second one is that onCharacteristicRead is only called one despite calling him on more than 10 READABLE characteristics

I'm only testing things out for now but here's what I did:

```
    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);
        for (BluetoothGattService serv: gatt.getServices()) {
            System.out.println("-----------------" + serv.getUuid());
            
            for(BluetoothGattCharacteristic chara: serv.getCharacteristics()) {
                
                if((chara.getProperties() & PROPERTY_READ) != 0) {
                    System.out.println("Can read");
                    gatt.readCharacteristic(chara);
                } 
                else {
                    System.out.println("Can't read");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,  int status) {
        super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, status);
        System.out.println("Called");

        if(status == GATT_SUCCESS) {
            System.out.println(new String(characteristic.getValue()));
        } else {
            System.out.println("error during read");
        }
    }
```

And this is the output:

```
    I/System.out: -----------------00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    I/System.out: Can read
    I/chatty: uid=10168(com.example.adici) Binder:27154_2 identical 1 line
    I/System.out: Can read
    I/System.out: -----------------00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    I/System.out: Can't read
    I/System.out: -----------------3ab10100-f831-4395-b29d-570977d5bf94
    I/System.out: Can read
    I/System.out: Can read
    I/System.out: Can't read
    I/System.out: Can read
    I/System.out: Can read
    I/System.out: -----------------0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    I/System.out: Can read
    I/System.out: Can read
    I/System.out: -----------------0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    I/System.out: Can read
    I/System.out: Called
    I/System.out: DISTO 80951028
```

I've also tried adding this while loop to wait for the last callback to happen before starting another one as it was mentionned

```
while(waitingForCallback)
{
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
waitingForCallback = true;
gatt.readCharacteristic(chara);
```

Where waitingForCallback is set to false in onCharacteristicRead but it ends up in infinite loop as the method is not called

I really don't get why the overload is a problem for my IDE as Sdkmin = 27 and targetSdk = 31

Any help is appreciated !

Comment: (note that DISTO 809... is the device name)

Comment: Just a few hints. GATT Services *Generic Access* (0x1800), *Generic Attribute* (0x1801), *Device Information* (0x180A) and *Battery* (0x180F) are not the ones you are searching for. If your are interested in them have a look at the [Core Specification](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/core-specification-5-3/).

Comment: You are searching for the  *bad boy*. A quick search reveals that already someone wrote about it here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69629692/how-to-read-laser-distance-measure-via-web-bluetooth and at github there is an Android App that seems to support your device: https://github.com/d7knight/Easy-Check-Measure-App/blob/master/Disto%20App/src/main/java/com/example/david/distoapp/SampleGattAttributes.java

Comment: Thanks for doing my research job ahah '^^ You really made my day finding this, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not initiate a gatt operation (for example reading a characteristic) while an operation is already pending. You must wait for the callback before you initiate the next read.

You sleep loop won't work since the Bluetooth stack never calls a callback of yours while another callback is already running. In this case if you run that sleep loop in onServicesDiscovered, the onCharacteristicRead callback will be scheduled to run, but it won't run until onServicesDiscovered has returned. This is a feature of the "Binder" mechanism in Android, which prevents callbacks for the same object to run concurrently.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i'll go check this out.

Comment: Still is it ok to call a method with callback from within a callback ? I call discoverServices from onConnectionStateChange

Comment: Yes that's totally fine.